# Adding namespace declaration to existing XML with Groovy+Smooks

Tags: xml, groovy, namespaces, declaration

I'm writing this groovy script that runs inside Smooks and edits an XML. I'm trying to add xsi:nil="true" to the empty fields and the problem I'm having is that the xsi namespace declaration isn't added to the root field. Here's what I tried:

```
element['@xsi:nil'] = 'true'
```

and

```
def nil = doc.createAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", 'xsi:nil')
nil.setValue('true');
element.setAttributeNodeNS(nil)
```

Both of these will add the attribute but not the NS declaration.

I also tried this but it results in a stack overflow error:

```
def doc = element.getOwnerDocument();
doc.declareNamespace(xsi: 'http://www.example.org/xsi')
```

Here's the link to the Smooks documentation:
http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=V1.4:groovy

Basically the script runs inside a groovy class that is generated at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

try formatting the element as shown below:

```
 "elementname"('xsi:nil' : 'true', 'xmlns:xsi' : 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')
```

this will return the following XML tag:

```
<elementname xsi:nil='true' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' />
```

Hope this solves your problem.